# How to run python script from java without storing the script in a .py file?

Tags: java, python

I would like to execute a python script which is obtained as a web request, execute the script and send the output as response.

So far, I have written the python script into a .py file and executed it using the ProcessBuilder.

The problem is, once the script has been executed, there is no use in storing the script in the server. So I delete the file once the execution is completed.

Now I feel this is a bad approach and would like to minimise the write and delete operations.

I tried using [jpserve](https://github.com/johnhuang-cn/jpserve) but it is not working as expected. (When a selenium test case is given as input to jpserve, it is not processing the scripts but still sending the success message.) Also I am not interested in using jython.

Is there a way to run the python scripts without storing it in a .py file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also probably run the script like this :

```java
String script = "your script from server";
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("python3", "-c", script);
pb.start();
```

In a shell the python -c allow you to run a script that you write in the shell.

Answer (score 0):

Jython: Python for the Java Platform - http://www.jython.org/index.html

Also, isn't that terribly unsafe?